# How can I use Mission Control and Flight Recorder with a JavaFX bundled EXE

Tags: deployment, profiling, exe, javafx-8

I would like to profile my JavaFX application once it's been bundled and deployed out as an EXE.

I am not sure how to start the JVM with the needed options on the local machine.

I am just using this in development to see what the memory footprint looks like.

Once bundled I have "myapp.exe" which I double click on - I would like to profile from there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running flight recorder, the VM will prompt to enable it on the local VM - so you can activate it from the Mission Control VM.